# (iphone) audio format to play voice sound?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, aac

Is there a preferred audio format to play voice recording?

play time is about 1-5secs.

AAC is considered bad for this?

I'm trying to play aac with AVAudioPlayer but having -1 error.
AVAudioplayer isn't suitable for aac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be some codec problems...

Try to convert your audio files from the itunes..